# problems with multiples invitations to a event on facebook

Tags: facebook

I'm tried use the multiples invitations method of facebook-graph API. 
of according the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/),this is the syntax to send multiples invitations:

> /EVENT_ID/invited?users=USER_ID1,USER_ID2,USER_ID3

I wrote this code:

```
$ids = 'id123,id12345';
    $ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/$e_id/invited?users=$ids?access_token={$token}");
        curl_setopt_array($ch,
            array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'
            )
        );
```

I'm getting the following error:

**{"error":{"message":"(#114) An id must be a valid ID string (e.g., \"123\")","type":"OAuthException"}}**

How I fix this? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is written in error message it should be numeric strings i.e. "12345" and not "id12345", try real uids and don't invite your own uid.

hope this helps